# Background-color/image not covering the width of the div on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

(On mobiles devices only: android, ios)

I am not quite sure what is going on here, but I do know that the `background-color` at the top isn't spanning the entire div length. Also the `background-images` near the footer isn't centering to the middle. I have tried many different things to remedy the problem but it looks like the top background-color issue and the footer background-image issue are related because they both have similar 'cut off' points.

Both elements share similar code. A parent div that is absolutely positioned with a centered inner div. Any insight would be great.

Website is [here](http://www.seascapekidsfun.com/).

**Update**: I tried to replicate the issue on jsFiddle here (reminded: use a mobile browser): http://jsfiddle.net/zmwgg279/2/

Comment: Can you please provide some code to demonstrate your issue, otherwise if you fix it, the link in this questions will no longer demonstrate your issue to others.

Comment: Ok let me try that, but I don't know if the code will accurately display the problem because of it only being a mobile problem. I'll try to get similar results on jsfiddle.

Comment: @Timmah okay I added a jsFiddle example. It doesn't visually look the same on desktop, but the code is the same and it has similar results on the mobile browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are specifying conflicting `width`s for your wrapper elements.

Here's the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/ecbnjkbe/)**

Your first element, `#seascape-infobar` has a `width` of `100%`, which is perfect for a responsive layout. Where it breaks is that you are forcing a child element to be potentially wider than the screen on which it displays. Here's a simplified version of your code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="seascape-infobar">
    <div class="wrap"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#seascape-infobar {
    width: 100%;
}
#seascape-infobar .wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px; /* What happens when this is wider than the screen? Break! */
}
```

When you view this on a mobile, which has a screen width *lower* than `980px`, the parent wrapper `#seascape-infobar` will still fit the screen width correctly, but the *child* element `.wrap` will be forced to overflow to `980px`.

The safest practice here is to ensure all your widths are being specified using relative units like `%` or `ems`. This allows content to adjust cleanly to the display on which it is viewed.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so throughly. Helped me fix a different but similar issue pertaining to sizing of the elements!